# How to position a div made "box" with HTML

Tags: html, css

I have tried align, position, and others. This problem couldn't be found because I would find topics relative to this discussing the `<div>` "function" but I need the solution for the `div{}`

Here's my code:

```
div{background-color: White;    opacity:0.7;    width: 380px;    height: 325px;}
```

So how do I position it to be in a specific spot, or even use simple keywords like align center or such. I have tried `align:center;` and `position:center;`(out of curiosity) but none did what I thought it would do. So how do I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using position, top, and left to put your div wherever you want. Like this:

```
div{
    background-color: #000; 
    opacity:0.7; 
    width: 380px; 
    height: 325px; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 300px;
}
```

If you want your div to be centered you can also play with the margin:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way's, you can make another class like `.main-container` and position through the margin like

```
.main-container
{
margin-left:200px;
}
```

now in html write your div inside the maincontainer class like

```
<div class="main-container">
{
<div class="your class here">

your data
</div>
</div>
```

you can also play with margin, and for more information google it...

this is the simplest and easy way to apply as well as to understand, hope it will solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the div? Based on your last sentence: "align:center; and position:center;" that's what it sounds like. Because you've defined a width already, and assuming that other styles are not interfering the following should work to center your div: (notice the margin)

```
div { background-color: White; opacity:0.7; width: 380px; height: 325px; margin:0 auto; }
```

Otherwise, if you are trying  position the div anywhere else, do a search for positions absolute and static.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.My_div {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here are some examples! http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical